# Get /users/me details from Wordpress backend

Tags: customization, api

**Is there anyway to get the same details as /users/me api command but in WP backend?**

I have backend function that would get the user meta details

**custom api /user_meta**

```
public myFunc( $userId ) {
    $user_meta = get_user_meta( $userId );

    return $user_meta
}
```

The user meta field has an **ACF option** that is formatted strange

```
"place": [
    "a:1:{i:0;s:12:\"Earth\";}"
],
```

But when using the /users/me API call, the return is

**/users/me default wp api**

```
"place": [
    "Earth"
],
```

Although I could use a conjunction of both apis to get the proper user meta details, it isn't ideal. Is there anyway of getting the /users/me api call in wordpress backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"a:1:{i:0;s:12:\"Earth\";}"
```

This is a PHP serialized value. If you pass it to [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) you'll get back the array you're expecting. (And it looks like you've edited it because "Earth" is not 12 characters long: that should be `s:5:"Earth"`.)

However I'm surprised that get_user_meta doesn't already do this for you: it passes the value it's fetched from the database through [maybe_unserialize()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) before it's returned to you, which ought to do this automatically for you. Is there any chance you've double-serialized this before storing the string in the database? (And note also the warning on the documentation page about unserializing arbitrary user-provided strings.)

To answer the general question though, everything you can get from /users/me is available with normal API calls and you don't need to use the REST API from inside WordPress itself.